# How can I create a GetRequest that returns a generic list as return value? (Spring Boot)

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I have the following data in my table Config :

```
INSERT INTO profi.config_table(id, description, schema_name,table_name, columns)
    VALUES ('1','Description1','schema1','table1','[{''id'': 1,''analyticId'': 1,''propertytype'': shape,''minVal'': ,''maxVal'': ,''StringVal'': ''0200711'',''caseElse'': 0,''result'': ''kugel''},{''id'': 2,''analyticId'': 1,''propertytype'': shape,''minVal'': ,''maxVal'': ,''StringVal'': ''0200712'',''caseElse'': 0,''result'': ''rechteck''},{''id'': 3,''analyticId'': 1,''propertytype'': shape,''minVal'': ,''maxVal'': ,''StringVal'': ''0200713'',''caseElse'': 0,''result'': ''prism''},{''id'': 4,''analyticId'': 1,''propertytype'': shape,''minVal'': ,''maxVal'': ,''StringVal'': ''0200714'',''caseElse'': 0,''result'': ''pyramid''},{''id'': 5,''analyticId'': 1,''propertytype'': shape,''minVal'': ,''maxVal'': ,''StringVal'': ,''caseElse'': 1,''result'': ''flag''},{''id'': 6,''analyticId'': 1,''propertytype'': color,''minVal'': 0,''maxVal'': 20,''StringVal'': ,''caseElse'': 0,''result'': ''grun''},{''id'': 7,''analyticId'': 1,''propertytype'': color,''minVal'': 21,''maxVal'': 50,''StringVal'': ,''caseElse'': 0,''result'': ''gelb''},{''id'': 8,''analyticId'': 1,''propertytype'': color,''minVal'': 51,''maxVal'': 80,''StringVal'': ,''caseElse'': 0,''result'': ''hellblau''},{''id'': 9,''analyticId'': 1,''propertytype'': color,''minVal'': 81,''maxVal'': 999,''StringVal'': ,''caseElse'': 0,''result'': ''rot''},{''id'': 10,''analyticId'': 1,''propertytype'': color,''minVal'': ,''maxVal'': ,''StringVal'': ,''caseElse'': 1,''result'': ''lila''},{''id'': 11,''analyticId'': 1,''propertytype'': size,''minVal'': 0,''maxVal'': 0,''StringVal'': ,''caseElse'': 0,''result'': ''5''},{''id'': 12,''analyticId'': 1,''propertytype'': size,''minVal'': 0.01,''maxVal'': 0.35,''StringVal'': ,''caseElse'': 0,''result'': ''11''},{''id'': 13,''analyticId'': 1,''propertytype'': size,''minVal'': 0.36,''maxVal'': 0.70,''StringVal'': ,''caseElse'': 0,''result'': ''12''},{''id'': 14,''analyticId'': 1,''propertytype'': size,''minVal'': 0.71,''maxVal'': 1.11,''StringVal'': ,''caseElse'': 0,''result'': ''13''},{''id'': 15,''analyticId'': 1,''propertytype'': size,''minVal'': 1.12,''maxVal'': 1.89,''StringVal'': ,''caseElse'': 0,''result'': ''14''},{''id'': 16,''analyticId'': 1,''propertytype'': size,''minVal'': 1.90,''maxVal'': 10.00,''StringVal'': ,''caseElse'': 0,''result'': ''15''}]');
INSERT INTO profi.config_table(id, description, schema_name,table_name, columns)
    VALUES ('2','Description1','schema2','analyticIcon','[{''id'': 1,''indexNummer'': 1,''indexName'': ''Kosten'',''minVal'': 0.0,''maxVal'': 0.0,''indexWert'': 0},{''id'': 2,''indexNummer'': 1,''indexName'': ''Kosten'',''minVal'': 0.01,''maxVal'': 1.9,''indexWert'': 1},{''id'': 3,''indexNummer'': 1,''indexName'': ''Kosten'',''minVal'': 1.91,''maxVal'': 5.99,''indexWert'': 2},{''id'': 4,''indexNummer'': 1,''indexName'': ''Kosten'',''minVal'': 6.0,''maxVal'': 17.2,''indexWert'': 3},{''id'': 5,''indexNummer'': 1,''indexName'': ''Kosten'',''minVal'': 17.21,''maxVal'': 73.3,''indexWert'': 4},{''id'': 6,''indexNummer'': 1,''indexName'': ''Kosten'',''minVal'': 73.31,''maxVal'': 9999999.99,''indexWert'': 5},{''id'': 7,''indexNummer'': 2,''indexName'': ''Zustandsänderung'',''minVal'': 0.0,''maxVal'': 0.0,''indexWert'': 0},{''id'': 8,''indexNummer'': 2,''indexName'': ''Zustandsänderung'',''minVal'': 0.1,''maxVal'': 0.1,''indexWert'': -1},{''id'': 9,''indexNummer'': 2,''indexName'': ''Zustandsänderung'',''minVal'': 0.2,''maxVal'': 0.4,''indexWert'': -2},{''id'': 10,''indexNummer'': 2,''indexName'': ''Zustandsänderung'',''minVal'': 0.5,''maxVal'': 1.0,''indexWert'': -3},{''id'': 11,''indexNummer'': 2,''indexName'': ''Zustandsänderung'',''minVal'': 1.1,''maxVal'': 3.0,''indexWert'': -2},{''id'': 12,''indexNummer'': 2,''indexName'': ''Zustandsänderung'',''minVal'': -0.2,''maxVal'': -0.1,''indexWert'': 1},{''id'': 13,''indexNummer'': 2,''indexName'': ''Zustandsänderung'',''minVal'': -0.6,''maxVal'': -0.3,''indexWert'': 2},{''id'': 14,''indexNummer'': 2,''indexName'': ''Zustandsänderung'',''minVal'': -3.0,''maxVal'': -0.7,''indexWert'': 3},{''id'': 15,''indexNummer'': 3,''indexName'': ''Kosten'',''minVal'': 0.0,''maxVal'': 0.0,''indexWert'': 0},{''id'': 16,''indexNummer'': 3,''indexName'': ''Kosten'',''minVal'': 0.01,''maxVal'': 0.6,''indexWert'': 1}, {''id'': 17,''indexNummer'': 3,''indexName'': ''Kosten'',''minVal'': 0.61,''maxVal'': 1.5,''indexWert'': 2},{''id'': 18,''indexNummer'': 3,''indexName'': ''Kosten'',''minVal'': 1.51,''maxVal'': 4.0,''indexWert'': 3},{''id'': 19,''indexNummer'': 3,''indexName'': ''Kosten'',''minVal'': 4.01,''maxVal'': 20.0,''indexWert'': 4},{''id'': 20,''indexNummer'': 3,''indexName'': ''Kosten'',''minVal'': 20.01,''maxVal'': 9999999.99,''indexWert'': 5},{''id'': 21,''indexNummer'': 4,''indexName'': ''Gewichtung'',''minVal'': 0.0,''maxVal'': 20.0,''indexWert'': 1},{''id'': 22,''indexNummer'': 4,''indexName'': ''Gewichtung'',''minVal'': 21.0,''maxVal'': 50.0,''indexWert'': 1},{''id'': 24,''indexNummer'': 4,''indexName'': ''Gewichtung'',''minVal'': 81.0,''maxVal'': 999.0,''indexWert'': 1},{''id'': 25,''indexNummer'': 5,''indexName'': ''Verfallsindex'',''minVal'': 0.0,''maxVal'': 0.0,''indexWert'': 0},{''id'': 26,''indexNummer'': 5,''indexName'': ''Verfallsindex'',''minVal'': 0.01,''maxVal'': 0.17,''indexWert'': 1},{''id'': 27,''indexNummer'': 5,''indexName'': ''Verfallsindex'',''minVal'': 0.18,''maxVal'': 0.35,''indexWert'': 2},{''id'': 28,''indexNummer'': 5,''indexName'': ''Verfallsindex'',''minVal'': 0.36,''maxVal'': 0.54,''indexWert'': 3},{''id'': 29,''indexNummer'': 5,''indexName'': ''Verfallsindex'',''minVal'': 0.55,''maxVal'': 0.7,''indexWert'': 4},{''id'': 30,''indexNummer'': 5,''indexName'': ''Verfallsindex'',''minVal'': 0.71,''maxVal'': 0.9,''indexWert'': 5},{''id'': 31,''indexNummer'': 5,''indexName'': ''Verfallsindex'',''minVal'': 0.91,''maxVal'': 1.11,''indexWert'': 6},{''id'': 32,''indexNummer'': 5,''indexName'': ''Verfallsindex'',''minVal'': 1.12,''maxVal'': 1.5,''indexWert'': 7},{''id'': 33,''indexNummer'': 5,''indexName'': ''Verfallsindex'',''minVal'': 1.51,''maxVal'': 1.89,''indexWert'': 8},{''id'': 34,''indexNummer'': 5,''indexName'': ''Verfallsindex'',''minVal'': 1.9,''maxVal'': 5.9,''indexWert'': 9},{''id'': 35,''indexNummer'': 5,''indexName'': ''Verfallsindex'',''minVal'': 5.91,''maxVal'': 10.0,''indexWert'': 10},{''id'': 23,''indexNummer'': 4,''indexName'': ''Gewichtung'',''minVal'': 51.0,''maxVal'': 75.0,''indexWert'': 1}]');
```

Via Spring Boot I want to create several requests to query or edit the data.

Request 1) GetAll

in this request I want to get the table Config. This works already.

Request 2) GetConfigByTablename

in this request I get the row from the table Config according to the column table_name.
This works as well.

Request 3) GetColumnsByTablename

in this request I want to get only the field columns from the corresponding row as json depending on the table_name. But the content of columns can differ depending on the row. I want to make this request generic. However, I do not get on here and need your help.

HERE IS MY TRY:
My Controller

```
     public <T> ResponseEntity<List<T>> getConfigValuesByTableName(String
     tableName) {
     final Config configValueFound =
     configService.getConfigValueByTableName(tableName);
    
     if (configValueFound != null) {
     return ResponseEntityBuilderUtils.ok(configValueFound);
     } else {
         return new ResponseEntity<List<T>>(configValueFound, HttpStatus.OK);
     }
     }
```

My Service

```
public Config getConfigValueByTableName(String tableName);
```

My ServiceImpl

```
@Override
    public AnalyticIcon getAnalyticIconValues(String tableName) {

        AnalyticIcon analyticIcon = null;
        final Optional<ConfigEntity> configEntityOptional = configDAO.findByTableName(tableName);

        if (configEntityOptional.isPresent()) {
            final ConfigEntity configEntity = configEntityOptional.get();
            configMapper.toMapConfigEntitytoDTO(configEntity);

            String jsonString = configEntity.getColumns();

            try {
                analyticIcon = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, AnalyticIcon.class);
            } catch (JsonParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return analyticIcon;
```

My Repository

```
Optional<ConfigEntity> findByTableName(String tableName);
```

Request 4) PutColumnsByTablename

in this request I want to change the data that are in column. But for this I need request 3.

Can someone tell me how to create a request that returns a generic list with the data from "columns"?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

maybe ,you should just treat the "column" as String  and let the caller of your api to use javascript , or something else ,to handle the json.

The caller of your api first use "tableName" as parameter to get the columns .  This means the caller have the message themselves to determine what column they get and what kind of json the column is. So just let the caller to handle the json .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).